# I have a lambda function in which I am fetching a csv file from s3 now I want to run SQL query on that data in node.js?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function in which I am fetching a csv file from s3 now I want to run **SQL query on that csv or query on JSON**(after converting csv into JSON) which is best and easiest approch for this in **node.js**. As I want to use group by query so S3 select is not possible?

Comment: some sample code would help

Comment: How many lines are in the file? What is the total file size? How complex is your query and could you instead just write equivalent code to do the query?

Comment: I have around 200 lines file which is downloaded from s3. I want to use group by of SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found module "querycsv" in python , so I changed  environment of code to Python. https://pythonhosted.org/querycsv/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) which helps you to run more complex querieson the files in S3.